# Does anyone know how I can read emails in PHP and then write them to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, email, imap

I'm doing an internship right now and I'm supposed to implement the question from above. On google I find nothing that fits.
I need help that emails are read (with the help of Imap), then written into a database (mysql). Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this, so I turn to you.
Thanks in advance.

I don't know how this works, I have no idea where to start.
I am glad about help!

This was an Attempt:

```
<?php 

// POP3-Server 
$host="xxx"; 
$port=" 993"; 
// User-Daten 
$user="xxx"; 
$passwort="xxx"; 

// Verbinden zur Mailbox 
$mailbox=imap_open("{".$host."/imap:    993}INBOX",$user,$passwort); 

// Überprüfen ob Verbindung erfolgreich
if ($mailbox) 
{ 
// Posteingang überprüfen 
$check=imap_check($mailbox); 
// Anzahl vorhandener Emails im Postfach 
$count_msg=$check->Nmsgs; 
// Anzahl neuer Emails im Postfach 
$count_new_msg=$check->Recent; 
// Emails auslesen 
for ($i=1; $i<=imap_num_msg($mailbox); 
$i++) 

{ 



// Header erfassen 
$mail_header=imap_header($mailbox, $i); 

// Datum erfassen 
$mail_date=$mail_header->Date; 

// Mail-ID erfassen 
$mail_id=$mail_header->message_id; 

// Empfänger erfassen 
$mail_to=$mail_header->toaddress; 

// Absendername erfassen 
$mail_from_name=$mail_header->from [0]->personal; 

// Absender-eMail-Adresse erfassen 
$mail_from_address=$mail_header->from [0]->mailbox."@".$mail_header->from [0]->host; 

// Kopieempfänger erfassen 
$mail_copy_to=$mail_header->cc[0] ->mailbox."@".$mail_header->cc[0] ->host; 

// Antwortempfänger erfassen 
$mail_answer_to=$mail_header->reply_to; 

// Betreff erfassen 
$mail_subject=$mail_header->subject; 

// Nachricht erfassen
$mail_body = imap_body($mailbox,$i); 


// Daten in db speichern
include ("config.inc.php");

  $eintrag = "INSERT INTO bsi_statistik (komponente, anzahlmeldungen, datumletztemeldung, mailsin30tagen) VALUES ('$komponente', '$mail_from_address', '$mail_subject', '$mail_date', '$mail_body')";
  $eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);

echo "e-Mail Nr.".$i."<br>"; 
// Ausgabe in HTML 
echo '<b>Versendet am:</b> '; 
echo $mail_date."<br>"; 

echo '<b>Eindeutige eMail-ID: </b>'; 
echo $mail_id."<br>"; 

echo '<b>Empfänger: </b>'; 
echo $mail_to."<br>"; 

echo '<b>"Name des Absenders: </b>'; 
echo $komponente."<br>"; 

echo '<b>"eMail des Absenders: </b>'; 
echo $mail_from_address."<br>"; 
// echo $mail_from_address."<br>"; 

echo '<b>Betreff: </b>'; 
echo $mail_subject."<br><br>"; 

echo '<b>Nachricht: </b>'; 
echo $mail_body."<br><br>"; 


// E-Mail löschen löschen
 imap_delete($mailbox, $i); 


} 
imap_expunge($mailbox);
imap_close($mailbox); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Hey @Moritz - Welcome to StackOverflow. When creating questions, can you please provide examples of any code you've tried so far. You may also want to check out the Laminas/Mail package for retrieval of email: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mail/read/

Comment: As stated by @PeterB, please show what you have attempted.  (side-note: To start with , please (1) study imap_mail, then (2) study MySQLi (or PDO)  functions)

Comment: Hey,
that's the problem, I have no idea how to use it, that's why I ask here.

Comment: This was an Attempt:

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your attempt?

Comment: IMAP, not a first project, when you are starting out. Having said that, use `Mutt` a command line email client to pipe the messages to what ever you want.

Comment: Of course, I have changed it.

Comment: My "boss" told me to do it with IMAP and find the way myself. And since I know that here are many experts in the field are on the road, I ask you

Comment: Please do not use mysql_query , this is outdated (So, use mysqli or pdo please)

Comment: Okay thanks, could you show me how else? With a code example how you use it or sth else?

Comment: see this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-emails-using-php-and-imap/

Answer (score 0):

**Updated with example from additional information provided by OP**

The easiest way to achieve this would be to do the following. This example uses the following database schema:

```sql
create table incoming_emails
(
    id int auto_increment,
    date_sent datetime null,
    headers json null,
    `from` varchar(191) null,
    subject text null,
    content longtext null,
    constraint incoming_emails_pk
        primary key (id)
);
```

Use Composer to import a new library, `laminas/mail`:

```
composer install laminas/mail
```

After doing so, mail can be retrieved and iterated over like so:

```
<?php

use Laminas\Mail\Storage\Imap;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Connecting with Imap:
$mail = new Imap([
    'host'     => 'example.com',
    'user'     => 'test',
    'password' => 'test',
]);

echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";
foreach ($mail as $message) {
    printf("Mail from '%s': %s\n", $message->from, $message->subject);
}
```

You can then persist to a database using the MySQLi class:

```
<?php

use Laminas\Mail\Storage\Imap;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Do all configuration here.
// Database:
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'RANDOM_PASSWORD';
$dbName = 'my_database';

// Email inbox to query:
$emailHost = 'localhost';
$emailPort = 995;
$emailUsername = 'email@example.com';
$emailPassword = 'SECRET_STRING_HERE';

// Do not edit below this line.

$mysqli = new MySQLi($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// If cannot connect to MySQL database, throw an error.
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    throw new \Exception('Could not connect to database!');
}

// Connecting with Imap:
$mail = new Imap([
    'host'     => $emailHost,
    'user'     => $emailUsername,
    'password' => $emailPassword,
    'port' => $emailPort,
]);

echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";

// Prepare a query.
$query = 'INSERT INTO `incoming_emails` (`date_sent`, `headers`, `from`, `subject`, `content`)';

// Prepare all emails for input to SQL database.
$mailParser = new MailMimeParser();

foreach ($mail as $message) {
    $queryData[] = [
        'from' => $mysqli->real_escape_string($message->getHeader('reply-to') ?? $message->getHeader('from')),
        'headers' => $mysqli->real_escape_string(json_encode($message->getHeaders())),
        'subject' => $mysqli->real_escape_string($message->getSubject()),
        'content' => $mysqli->real_escape_string($message->getContent()),
    ];
    
    // Left in for debug:
    printf("Mail from '%s': %s\n", $message->from, $message->subject);
}

$query .= 'VALUES (' . implode('), (', $queryData) . ')';

$mysqli->query($query);

echo 'Done';
```

Please ensure you also include good database input sanitisation.

*This is provided as-is, with no testing done so its not confirmed to work exactly. You likely will need to update this for your own needs and is provided as an educational example only.*

Docs:

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
2. https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mail/read/

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will try to apply this directly!
Really, thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, 
so with the INSERT, how do I do that, that the email is subdivided? I have created several columns at phpmyadmin, for DATE of the email, title of the email, so how do I do that, that is divided for each?
Do you also have a code example for this?

Comment: Provide me with your MySQL table schema, and I can advise on how to write the insert query.

Comment: Alternatively, for learning purposes, you may want to check out this link: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mail/read/#working-with-messages - You'll see methods for retrieving specific data, including headers. Headers is where the sent date/time would be populated for example.

Comment: I am from Germany, so my tables are only German, so in advance. 

First the id. Then 'CREATED TIMESTAMP', as 3. "komponente" , so the title of the email, as 4. "anzahlmeldungen" total emails, as 5. "datumletztemeldung" the last email, and as last "mailsin30tagen" the emails of the last 30 days as number, so how many

Comment: I would send you a link from Pastebin with my code, is that ok?

Comment: You don't need "mailsin30tagen" You could get that with a `$mysqli->query('SELECT count(id) FROM `email_table` WHERE `from_email` = \'randomPerson@example.com\');

This would mean you should store the from email. I recommend storing the following:

1. id
2. from_email
3. datetime (When it was sent)
4. headers (as a JSON string for reuse as you need)
5. subject
6. Email contents

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you show me a final result of the code? I would be glad!

Comment: Sure. I'll be home in about 90 minutes. I will write you out a full proof of concept. Doing all this from my phone.

Comment: All right!
Thank you really much, without you I would be lost!

Comment: Just send me a message then

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry for the long response time, I'm testing out the code now. Thanks a lot! @peter

Comment: @PeterSmith Hey, could I send you my code once now and you would look over? Best regards, Moritz